# How do I use a predefined variable/constant in my Cucumber testing Scenario

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have defined a variable as userid in env.rb.

> userid='1234'

In my Cucumber testing, Scenario, I wish to confirm that my response contains the correct userid. However, I do not wish to hard code the same in my Senario or step definition. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I wish to use "userid" in my Scenario step definition. By defining it as a constant or global, I can access it in ruby anywhere, but not in the scenario

I used it like this :-

> Then I should see "userid" set to "@userid" in the response

Answer (score 3):

I would place an additional file, let's say `test_constanst.rb` in the features/ dir. There, I would define a module like this:

```
module TestConstants
  def self.user_id
    1234
  end
end
```

Like this, you have it separated from test configuration and code. You would just have to requrire the file from `env.rb`.

Answer (score 2):

Variable scope in Ruby is controlled by sigils to some degree. Variables starting with $ are global, variables with @ are instance variables, @@ means class variables, and names starting with a capital letter are constants. Make the variable global and it will be available everywhere, i.e

> $userid='1234'

Comment: using global variable ($userid) works, but I wonder what happens when running multiple cucumber tests simultaenously.  Do we have any instance per cucumber testing process(or thread) which can be shared between env.rb and step_definitions?